# Why does this simple Windows bat file give error "Syntax incorrect"?

Tags: batch-file, window

This is in Windows 7. Here is my simple bat file to test if a parameter exists:

```
if [%1] EQU [] (
    echo No parameter given; usage: testparam <something>
    exit
) ELSE (
    echo You gave parameter: %1
)
```

When I run this (with no parameter) I get this error message:

```
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
```

Can anyone tell me what is wrong? Many other examples have this construct...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem is caused by the missing quotes in the echo statement for the missing argument

Because you didn't put quotes around the argument, cmd will see < as "read input from file `something>`" because "something>" isn't a valid file name in windows, it will say you used an invalid syntax

How to fix the problem:

```
echo "No parameter given; usage: testparam <something>"
```

Comment: Close :-) Actually, `<something` is valid syntax, though it will raise an error unless a file named "something" is found. The actual syntax error is the trailing `>` which is treated as output redirection with the required destination file missing. An alternative to quoting the output is to escape the special characters: `echo ..... ^<something^>`

Comment: Thanks much, that worked...Windows batch files are a real PITA!